# How to change eclipse console output color?

Tags: eclipse, console

I am running eclipse on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'd like to change console output color. I tried to edit it via Preferences>Run/Debug>Console>Background color but it doesn't work. Is there some other way to change?

Comment: There can be several consoles in the console view each with its own color configuration. Are you looking at the debug console or perhaps one of the Team (SVN, CVS) consoles?

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I managed to find a solution, howto is described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569364/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-navigator-view-in-eclipse